# Diff exiting with error code 1

Tags: java, exec, metric

I am trying to apply diff on two folders on the files which have same name.

I am checking name of files and then applying diff over them.

I am also calculating CKJM Metrics for them.

On running it is exiting with error code 1.

Kindly help in running CMD operations through java program .

```
Error : Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
Exited with error code 1
The common file names are [Inverse Trigono.doc, Limit _ Continuity & Differentia
bility.doc, Parabola.doc, Permutation and combination.doc, Probability.doc, Quad
ratic Equation and Expression.doc, Sequence and Series.doc, Solution of triangle
.doc, Straight Line.doc, TEST PAPER.rar, Vectors.doc]
```

p.s. I have gone through nearly all similar questions asked here but it seems like This is a bit different.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListFiles111 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Path of Folder 1
        String path1 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing"; 

            // Path of Folder 2
        String path2 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing"; 2

        File folder1 = new File(path1);
        File folder2 = new File(path2);

        ArrayList<String> commonfiles = new ArrayList<>();

            // Array list of files of folder 1 created.
        List<File> filesList1 = Arrays.asList(folder1.listFiles());

            // Array list of files of folder 1 created
        List<File> filesList2 = Arrays.asList(folder2.listFiles());


        for (File f1 : filesList1) 
        {
            if (f1.isFile()) 
            {
                for (File f2 : filesList2) 
                {
                    if (f2.isFile() && f1.getName().equals(f2.getName())) 
                    {
                                      // Adding common name files in new Array list
                        commonfiles.add(f1.getName());                                          
                        try 
                        {
                            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

                            String[] cmd = new String[5];
                            cmd[0] = "cmd.exe " ;
                            cmd[1] = "/C " ;
                            cmd[2] = "diff ";
                            cmd[3] = f1.getName() + " ";
                            cmd[4] = f2.getName();

                            Process pr = rt.exec( cmd );

                            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                            String line = null;

                            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
                            {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }

                            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                            System.out.println("Exited with error code "
                                    + exitVal);

                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try 
                        {
                            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

                            String[] cmdd = new String[6];
                            cmdd[0] = "cmd.exe " ;
                            cmdd[1] = "/C " ;
                            cmdd[2] = "java ";
                            cmdd[3] = "-jar ";
                            cmdd[4] = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Desktop\\ckjm-1.9\\build\\ckjm-1.9.jar ";
                    cmdd[5] = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Desktop\\*.class";

                            Process pr = rt.exec( cmdd );

                            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                            String line = null;

                            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
                            {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }

                            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                            System.out.println("Exited with error code "
                                    + exitVal);

                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The common file names are " + commonfiles);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"On compilation it is exiting with error code 1..."` -- so the code won't compile (and obviously won't run)? And you're seeing no other compiler error message? Or does the program actually *run* and then you see an exception message? Please post all errors and messages here with your question.

Comment: Edit: you're not giving reliable information. I see where you're seeing the error code, and it's coming from your program, so your program **must** compile and run for you to see this. Please clarify your problem, and please be accurate.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Done.... Kindly check.. Program is compiling

Comment: What is your OS, any other information about your environment? You've still not posted the error messages as text. Also, what program is "diff"? It's typically a unix utility and you appear to be running it on Windows.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : First of all it takes time to copy from Cmd...

Comment: Windows 7...  Using diff utility to run it.. 
Have set path already and diff is working alright on cmd..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Alive Still... ???

Comment: Again, I've never heard of this diff utility. You will need to explore this utility more and find out when and why it won't work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I have read almost everything about it... 
and playing with it since last 7 days... 
Only Issue I am having is with f1 and f2 as arguments in diff...

Comment: Where did you get diff from?

Comment: diff utility...
Do you people google before asking anything... 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

Comment: re `"diff utility... Do you people google before asking anything..."` -- There are 100's of diff utilities, and we're supposed to magically know which one you might just happen to be using -- how? By magic? Rather than being a presumptuous ****, try giving all pertinent information in your question. Have fun with this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `ProcessBuilder` instead of Runtime.exec(), it allows you a lot more control than Runtime.exec(), and will allow you to read the stdout and stderr of the utility you are calling, which will help you find the cause of your problem.

Another thing is you pass your files to your utility using `File.getName()` which is only going to return the name of the file itself, not its complete path. Therefore, your `diff` utility will interpret those file names according to its working directory, which is probably different from the folder where your files are stored. To solve this, you can either use `ProcessBuilder` to set the working directory before invoking your utility, or you can use `File.getAbsolutePath()` or `File.getCanonicalPath()` to pass the full path.

I'm not sure if it is relevant on Windows, but have you tried removing the trailing spaces from the arguments you pass to `Runtime.exec()`? Remember that you are not actually building a command string. The arguments that you pass to `Runtime.exec()` will be passed "as-is" to your operating system, and will end up "as-is" in the created process. in your case, this means that your OS will be looking for a binary called "cmd.exe ", which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist. Same goes for all your other parameters.

Also, Don't call "cmd.exe", call your program directly. What's the point of calling the shell and telling it to open your program. Just open the program directly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this, even though it is old because I was just looking for something similar. 
The return code '1' is from cmd.exe and indicates a "partial" issue according to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194959(v=vs.100).aspx link. It may not be getting as far as running "diff" at all. Or perhaps, as suggested above, cmd.exe cannot find the files to pass as in/output to diff. Again, this would result in diff not actually being called and the return code coming from the shell; not the diff program.
Hth